# How can we automate the task of setting windows desktop wallpaper through Firefox "set wallpaper" facility?

Tags: windows, batch-file, firefox, exe, wallpaper

If we open any image in firefox, and right click it, it has an option to "set it as desktop wallpaper".

I am in search of a way to automate this task, such as creating a batch file which upon running will set a specific image as wallpaper using Firefox function.

Please note that I have to use firefox function to set desktop wallpaper. My user does not have rights to change wallpaper using windows' built-in functionality.

Comment: If they don't have the rights to change the wallpaper, then they don't have the rights, ***regardless*** of the technique used: Firefox, UI or commandline.

Comment: why firefox? you can just download the image and then set it as desktop...

Comment: @abelenky well, even after blocking the rights for system function to change wallpaper, third party apps can still be used to change wallpapers. Just that, user doesn't have rights to install third party apps either. Still they are able to change the wallpaper using firefox, which is pre-installed.

Comment: @npocmaka plz read the whole description.